# Inline Disabling of Firefox Spellcheck?

Tags: firefox, spell-checking, html-input

I researched this a while ago and can't remember how to do it. I want to be able to prevent Firefox from running it's spell-checking functionality on certain input fields from within the page. I know it's possible but can't remember how to set it up.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why? Firefox doesn't give any way to override your option, so it's just really annoying for users who want to use the browser spellcheck feature.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Talk about having a big "duh" moment! I found the answer after some trial & error:

```
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 5):

The "spellcheck" attribute is currently an extra feature available only in Firefox, but it is being [considered for inclusion in HTML5](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-spellchecking).

Answer (score 5):

add the attribute using JQuery $('.textarea_className').attr('spellcheck',false);

This will allow you to return a valid XHTML mark up. =)

Answer (score 2):

The downside of this is that the W3 strict validator gives - Attribute "spellcheck" is not a valid attribute.  Bad news for those of us with OCD that love to see 0 errors in validating our sites.