# Programmatically learn the results of spellcheck

Tags: javascript, html

Hello is there a programmatically(js) way to learn the results of spellcheck='true'?

E.g. if this textarea

```
<textarea class="my-textarea" spellcheck="true" ></textarea>
```

Has orthographically correct content?

Comment: If you want to basically check from a script whether the browser's spell check has failed for a particular element, then I think the answer is no. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317598/javascript-access-to-spell-checker-on-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin for that:

http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

"JavaScript SpellCheck" is the industry leading spellchecker plugin for javascript. It allows the developer to easily add and control spellchecking in almost any HTML environment. You can install it in about 5 minutes by copying a folder into your website.

You could also try this jQuery version (although it's not actively maintained at the time of this writing).

https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker

Comment: Hi OhHendrie. This plugin does not support the language i want to use.(Greek)

Comment: Unfortenately Greeks is only for tranlations in windows prompts. No in dictionaries :(