# How can I use JavaScript to change the default spellchecker in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spell-checking

How do I change a browser's default spellchecker.dictionary (is what Firefox uses for example) with JavaScript so users always type in the site's preferred version of English?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript access to spell checker on browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317598/javascript-access-to-spell-checker-on-browsers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't a duplicate of the other one because this person seems to be looking for how to change a specific configuration setting and the other one was how to detect if spell checking was turned on or off (which should be in the DOM), what this is asking for can't be done at this time as browsers don't support that level of web-side control (and we probably wouldn't want them too in most cases). Sorry.