# Javascript / jQuery / Node.js — Detect if Browser has marked words as misspelt

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, spell-checking

Is it possible, either with javascript, jQuery, or a Node.js package to detect if an editable word has been underlined by the browser's spell-checker?

*Edit*

I don't need to use the browser's spellchecker, just merely detect its underlining, even if it's at the element level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript access to spell checker on browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317598/javascript-access-to-spell-checker-on-browsers)

Comment: @BCartolo - Good find. Shame that it's not accessible. That discussion is more about using the browser's spellchecker, I don't so much need that, but I wonder if the underlining fires an event of any kind.

Comment: doubt it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery plugin **JavaScriptSpellCheck**

http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/jquery-spell-check/

Looks like it's as simple as including the base jQuery library along with the plugin code. Add the JavascriptSpellCheck plugin **after** jQuery:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="include.js"></script>
```

If it were me, I would rename that include.js to something like jquery-JavaScriptSpellCheck.js (or use another plugin).

With this plugin you can "capture" or create the event which triggers the mispellings. Just a quick glance at the plugin docs, I see a few live demos, namely this one:

http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JavaScript_Spell_Check_Function_Demo

Hope this helps.