# Spell check in text editor

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. Can anybody tell me how to create simple text editor with spell check using html JavaScript?
if anybody has code please send me.

Comment: Is [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) a good choice?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use an existing texteditor with spellchecker like [ckEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easy way to do it without javascript: [inline-disabling-of-firefox-spellcheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223940/inline-disabling-of-firefox-spellcheck)

And here are some good existing spell checkers: [free-spell-checkers-for-html-forms](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/02/free-spell-checkers-for-html-forms.html)